# undefined constant DIR_LOG Error with Opencart

Tags: php, opencart, opencart2.x, opencart-module

all of a sudden I am getting the following error which prevents me from logging in to my admin and it is also showing on header of the store front

```
Notice: Use of undefined constant DIR_LOG - assumed 'DIR_LOG' in /home/user/public_html/system/library/openbay/ebay.php on line 150Notice: Use of undefined constant DIR_LOG - assumed 'DIR_LOG' in /home/user/public_html/system/library/openbay/ebay.php on line 150Warning: rename(DIR_LOGebaylog.log,DIR_LOG_ebaylog_2015-10-25_00-23-22.log): No such file or directory in /home/user/public_html/system/library/openbay/ebay.php on line 150Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/user/public_html/admin/index.php:84) in /home/user/public_html/system/library/response.php on line 12
```

Here is the code in /home/user/public_html/system/library/openbay/ebay.php on line 150

```
rename(DIR_LOG . 'ebaylog.log', DIR_LOG . '_ebaylog_' . date('Y-m-d_H-i-s') . '.log');
```

and I checked and DIR_LOG is defined correctly in config.php
Any help to identify and fix the issue is highly appreciated

Comment: impossible to answer without code, yet alone find the right duplicate

Comment: @Fred-ii- What code should I share? this is standard opencart 2.0.3.1

Comment: the code where you're using `DIR_LOG`, in and around it. too many possible reasons for its failure. Hidden characters, quotes used...

Comment: @Fred-ii-   I added the code to the question, does it help?

Comment: see http://php.net/manual/en/function.define.php `define("CONSTANT", "Hello world.");` if `DIR_LOG` hasn't been defined like that example, then you will need to do that. `DIR_LOG` is just that; a constant. you need to show what's inside config.php to be sure and replacing actual credentials with fakes.

Comment: @Fred-ii- as I mentioned in question, it is correctly defined and it was working after exiting the admin and logging back now we get this error. No change to the code was made to cause the issue

Comment: @Fred-ii- I just figured out the issue with your help and posted the answer, it was a bug with Openbay Pro which was solved by defining LOGS, Thank you very much for your hint

Comment: you're welcome. Glad to see you found it, *cheers*

Comment: @Fred-ii- Thank you soooo much

Comment: anytime, always happy to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just fixed it by adding

```
define('DIR_LOG', '/home/schwann/public_html/system/logs/');
```

to /home/user/public_html/admin/config.php
Opencart has

```
define('DIR_LOGS', '/home/schwann/public_html/system/logs/');
```

by default but it looks like openbay pro has a bug and is using DIR_LOG instead of DIR_LOG**S** by defining LOG and LOG**S** both the problem will be solved.